# The fundamental group of the complement of badly embedded open $n$-ball in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, manifolds, counterexamples

> Let $\mathcal D^n$ be an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ such that $\mathcal
>  D^n$ is homeomorphic to $\{x\in \Bbb R^n:|x|<1\}$. Suppose $\Bbb R^n\setminus \mathcal D^n$ is path-connected. How bad can
> $\pi_1(\Bbb R^n\setminus \mathcal D^n)$ be? Is it always a trivial group when $n\geq 3$?

If $\mathcal D^n$ is the interior of a smoothly embedded (or locally flat) closed $n$-ball, then using collar neighborhood together with the Seifert-van Kampen theorem, one can show that $\pi_1(\Bbb R^n\setminus \mathcal D^n)=0$ when $n\geq 3$, and $\pi_1(\Bbb R^2\setminus \mathcal D^2)=\Bbb Z$.

I am looking for some bad pathological examples in dimensions $3$ and $2$ so that $\pi_1(\Bbb R^n\setminus \mathcal D^n)$ is non-abelian when $\dim=2$ and non-trivial when $\dim \geq 3$. Maybe it is not possible in $\dim=2$, but I believe there should be something in dimension $3$.

Comment: There are wild arcs in $R^n, n\ge 4$, whose complements is not simply-connected. By tinkering with the construction, you will likely obtain examples of $D^n$ embedded in $R^n, n\ge 4$, whose complements is not simply-connected.

Comment: A simple example where the fundamental group is nontrivial is $D^{n-1}\times\mathbb R$ where $D^{n-1}$ is the open unit ball in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$.